# Filing form I-485 and I-864 online

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

I just submitted form I-130 and I-130a online petitioning for my wife. I want to know if I should submit form I-485 concurrently on my USCIS account, or should it be my wifes account? As well as affidavit I-864 and my joint sponsor. Should the joint sponsor make their own account? Or should everything be on my USCIS account?

Answer (score 1):

I-485 cannot be filed online. So your wife must file her I-485, and all its supporting documents, including I-864 from you, by paper, with a copy of the I-130 receipt.